# Best way to install MS Access on a remote windows server?

Tags: ms-access

What's the best way to install MS Access on a remote windows server?

I do have a valid license for the product. 
I want to install it on a remote windows server, for development purposes.

Server is running Windows Server 2003.

Comment: What do you want to be able to do with access on the remote server? (Oh and this probably either a serverfault.com or superuser.com question... but I'm intrigued!)

Comment: Continue development of the application (web front end, access database backend) Eventual conversion to python + sqlite, but not yet.

Comment: It's never too early to stop using Access as your database backend :)

Comment: Eartz, now normally I'd be irritated at the suggestion to stop using Access as a back end as it gets a lot of disrespect.  <smile>  That said if you're planning any volume of updates on a web server then I agreed with you.  If mostly read only then not a big deal.

Comment: Are you using a Jet/ACE file as a data store, or an actual Access application that you want to run on the server (via Windows Terminal Server, I'd presume)? If the former, you don't need Access installed at all. If the latter, you just run the Access installer (or the installer for your app).

Comment: @david, The former. I use the jet file as datastore. The app is purely classic asp. I just know that building queries for ms access is best done from within ms access. It has slightly nonstandard SQL

Answer (score 2):

Zip the contents of the CD/DVD and upload to your server.  Then unzip and run the setup.exe.